# Specified cast is not valid using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I have a database that has an ID column and the ID column is a BIGINT type.  I believe my issue has to do with the converting the ID column for the proper type in order the insert code to work.  I have tried to convert it but could not get the right syntax.

Here is my code...

```
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("select ID, Name", con);
cmd1.Connection = con;
con.Open();
int result = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
sqlcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable(ID, Name) VALUES(@ID, @Name)";
sqlcmd.Parameters.Clear();
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = result;
```

Comment: this line `cmd1.Connection = con;` is redundant. what's the exact exception?

Comment: apart from cast issue, Why are you trying to insert record with same ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BIGINT` = 64-bit, so use either the C# `long` type or `System.Int64`.

Also, change this line:

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = result;
```

To this:

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = result;
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [`long`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ctetwysk.aspx):

```
long result = (long)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
```

Range: from `–9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`

Signed 64-bit integer `System.Int64`